# Place a div on the border of another circular div

Tags: css, html, webkit

I want to make a solar system and I've used two divs around my sun so far; a div to specify the orbit path, and earth, to follow that path. The problem is that I want to place the `#earth` div onto the `#earth-orbit` div which has a border-radius of `50%`. I've wrapped `#earth-orbit` around `#earth` like this:

```
<div id='sun'>
</div>

<div id='earth-orbit'>
    <div id='earth'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, in my css I have this so far:

```
#sun
{
    margin: auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

#earth-orbit
{
    margin: auto;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;

    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}

#earth
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

How do I place the `#earth` onto the curved border of the `#earth-orbit`?

Edit: It's easy to do it when you're not trying to simultaneously keep the whole system in the middle of the screen

Comment: Just because I saw this the other week, [**check this out!**](http://neography.com/experiment/circles/solarsystem/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
#sun
{
    margin: auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

#earth-orbit
{
    margin: auto;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;

    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}

#earth
{
position:absolute;
left:130px;
height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>


<div id='sun'>
</div>

<div id='earth-orbit'>
    <div id='earth'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just make static image, you can absolute position #earth:

```
#earth
  {
    position:absolute;
    top: -25px;

    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

and do not forget about:

```
#earth-orbit
{
    top: 25px; left: 25px; bottom: 25px; right: 25px;
    position: absolute;
}
```